# Security with using blockUI Login screens

Tags: jquery, security, blockui

I'm not currently working on a coding project that is trying to implement this, but I am curious...
I've seen JQuery Block UI login pages that basically block out a site as soon as you navigate to them if you do not have not yet authenticated... However, is this secure? I thought most browsers had options to disable client side scripting, therefore allowing the person just to turn off the Jquery functionality and surf at the very least the first page that is being blocked out... Any links or resources on this topic would be cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously just cosmetics. You need to ensure on the server that people cannot perform any actions they are not supposed to perform.

However, for paywalls like on NYC times they don't care about that kind of security - there are enough "dumb" people who think they HAVE to pay.

Comment: Well I mean I guess I already pretty much knew this to be the answer, but how would one actually do it, I know it sounds dark, but I'd almost like to see some sort of example... I've thought of using blockui in the past to enforce a site login.. Primarily because it is asthetically pleasing, but i'd like to specifically know how someone could get around it... is it as simple as just turning off a browser setting, or would you save a page locally strip the client code off and run it from your machine or something...

Comment: You can simply use firebug to disable the blocking element. If you want to make it harder, run a timer which redirects or recreates the element if it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

it is not secure. Actually nothing that relies on client side (js and html) is secure. The key is to secure the server side.